# Storing SQL output to variable and calling the variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-redshift

I am trying to fetch output from a SQL query and have that written to a variable. This is using Redshift DB

```
cur.execute(sql.SQL("""select prod_name,prod_category,count(*) from sales limit 5""")
sql_output = cur.fetchall()
```

The above extracts 5 records and stores it to sql_output. Now I am trying have that written to a table in a powerpoint slide as below:

```
name_1 = sql_output[0][0]
category_1 = sql_output[0][1]
count_1 = sql_output[0][3]
name_2 = sql_output[1][0]
category_2 = sql_output[1][1]
count_2 = sql_output[1][3]
name_3 = sql_output[2][0]
category_3 = sql_output[2][1]
count_3 = sql_output[2][3]
name_4 = sql_output[3][0]
category_4 = sql_output[3][1]
count_4 = sql_output[3][3]
name_5 = sql_output[4][0]
category_5 = sql_output[4][1]
count_5 = sql_output[4][3]

if len(sql_output) = []:
    table.cell(1, 0).text = str('NA')
    table.cell(1, 1).text = str('NA')
    table.cell(1, 2).text = str('NA')
elif:
    table.cell(1, 0).text = name_1
    table.cell(1, 1).text = str(category_1)
    table.cell(1, 2).text = str(count_1)
    table.cell(2, 0).text = name_2
    table.cell(2, 1).text = str(category_2)
    table.cell(2, 2).text = str(count_2)
    table.cell(3, 0).text = name_3
    table.cell(3, 1).text = str(category_3)
    table.cell(3, 2).text = str(count_3)
    table.cell(4, 0).text = name_4
    table.cell(4, 1).text = str(category_4)
    table.cell(4, 2).text = str(count_4)
    table.cell(5, 0).text = name_5
    table.cell(5, 1).text = str(category_5)
    table.cell(5, 2).text = str(count_5)
```

The below works just fine, however it the output is null then the above fails and get an error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: what do you want here? Why don't use a for loop? I see your code repeats many times

Comment: @ChienNguyen, I have also tried the loop as shown in my initial post(post edited) but I keep getting the index out of range error.. I am trying to figure how could I have this run without any error irrespective of the count of records the SQL returns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for index, row in enumerate(sql_output):
    table.cell(index+1, 0).text = row[0]
    table.cell(index+1, 1).text = str(row[1])
    table.cell(index+1, 2).text = str(row[3])
```